# how to create a custom Input radio button which have attributes inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using react styled components as styling in my project ok let me point out what actually i am feeling not right is the text between the box and also need to style it if it is checked

what i have tried ?

I craeted a outer div and inside it i put radio input which i display none and thought i can style the outer element but that make the radio button not clickable any solution to this problem if you present react specific solution will be great.

```css
.radio__input{
  display:none;
}

.radiobox{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
//i want the div radiobox to styled when one radiobox is selected

<div class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" class="radio__input" name="radio"/>
  XS
</div>
<div class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" class="radio__input" name="radio"/>
  S
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please revise to punctuate your sentences properly. It's very difficult to understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the radio button somewhere, for the sake of accessibility, and to still be able to select it.

A common solution to styling radio buttons is to style their `<label>` element instead, and use the [CSS Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to style it depending on the radio button’s state.

Some more things should be taken into account to make the component accessible to users who need assistive technology:

- you should also use `<fieldset>` to provide an accessible name to the option group, even though “Green” might be self-explanatory
- focus needs to be visible, and since you are hiding the radio button itself, one solution is to show it on the fieldset
- each radio button still needs an accessible name, so add some hidden text also inside the labels

```css
.color-options {
  display: flex;
  padding: .2em;
  gap: .4em;
}

.color-options:focus-within {
  outline: .2em solid blue;
}

.color-option {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

input:checked+.color-option {
  outline: .2em solid darkseagreen;
}

/* kudos to  Scott O'Hara 
   https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html */
.visually-hidden {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Color</legend>

  <div class="color-options">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="gray" id="color-gray" class="visually-hidden">
    <label class="color-option" style="background-color: gray" for="color-gray">
    <span class="visually-hidden">
    Gray
    </span>
  </label>

    <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" id="color-black" class="visually-hidden">
    <label class="color-option" style="background-color: black" for="color-black">
    <span class="visually-hidden">
    Black
    </span>
  </label>

    <input type="radio" name="color" value="darkgreen" id="color-darkgreen" class="visually-hidden">
    <label class="color-option" style="background-color: darkgreen" for="color-darkgreen">
    <span class="visually-hidden">
    Dark Green
    </span>
  </label>

  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used unique ids for every radio button, which is used by the `<label>` element's for attribute to associate the labels with the radio buttons. So now the input is also checked when the label is clicked. Then i just styled the initial and checked state. But remember that you can only style elements according to the checked state of an input when they are a sibling or children. You can't access the parent element like in this case the `.radiobox` container with pure css.

```css
.radiobox {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

input[type="radio"] {
  appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" id="s" name="radio"/>
  <label for="s">S</label>
</div>

<div class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" id="m" name="radio"/>
  <label for="m">M</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation or introduction would make this a better answer. See [answer].

Comment: Its a preety good answer but why i am seeing little bit white line from the top and left when the item is checked

Comment: You are kind of hiding the radio-button with the `appearance` property. While it seems to work currently, isn’t the [`none` value supposed to give it a primitive appearance](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#valdef-appearance-none) instead of hiding it? This might change in the future, so I guess it’s not a recommended way of hiding widgets.

Comment: @Andy I am just removing the default browser/device styles. For example when you want to customize the styling of a html button its always recommended to reset default styles first. In my case i used another workflow and styled the label but i would never recommend to hide it because in some browsers you will not be able to check it through the label when the input is hidden.

Comment: @sarangkkl maybe its because of the focus-state wich i have not styled in that example